# Acessing adjacent data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's imagine a simple scenario: A simple mail system in firebase in a tree like this:

```
{
 "users":{
    "user-0001":{
       "mailbox":{
        "user-0002":{
           "DSdljkdkd333klll":{
              "message":"Hi ! I am user-0002 and I sent to user-0001 a message"
           },
           "JjkJHHH8888Gggg2":{
              "message":"Hi ! It's Me, user-0002 again !"
           }
        }
     },
     "secretStuff":"Something Private - nobody can write anything here",
     "myContacts":"This is my contact list. Obviously just me can access"
    },
    "user-0002":{
       "mailbox":{
         "user-0056":{
           "DSdljkdkd333klll":{
              "message":"Party tonight ! Don't forget !"
           }
        },
        "user-0282":{
           "3893NJJj33333eddf":{
              "message":"How are you ?"
           }
        }
     },
     "secretStuff":"Something Private - nobody can write anything here",
     "myContacts":"This is my contact list. Obviously just me can access"
  }
 }
}
```

Me as **user-0002** , I can write on my own tree.

Ok, but I should be capable to write at user-*/mailbox/user-0002 because I can send a message to any user that I want. And of course: I can't have access to any other key.

So, how to archive this : A rule where I can write on my tree and in an adjacent tree like the example above ?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep public data and private data in separate top-level lists. So:

```
mailboxes
  user-0001
    user-0002:{
      "DSdljkdkd333klll":{
       "message":"Hi ! I am user-0002 and I sent to user-0001 a message"
      },
      "JjkJHHH8888Gggg2":{
       "message":"Hi ! It's Me, user-0002 again !"
      }
    }
  user-0002
    user-0056:{
      "DSdljkdkd333klll":{
       "message":"Party tonight ! Don't forget !"
      }
    },
    user-0282:{
      "3893NJJj33333eddf":{
       "message":"How are you ?"
      }
    }
contacts
  user-0001: "This is my contact list. Obviously just me can access"
  user-0002: "This is my contact list. Obviously just me can access"
secrets
  user-0001: "Something Private - nobody can write anything here"
  user-0002: "Something Private - nobody can write anything here"
```

Now you can secure access based on the type of information, and load specific types of information.

If you need all information for a specific user, you will need to read from all three places. But given that you'll usually do this for a specific user, those reads are not a scalability concern. Even if you need all info for multiple users, it's usually quite fast since [Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Also see:

- [Firebase: How to structure public/private user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data)
- [How to create public/private user profile with Firebase security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921824/how-to-create-public-private-user-profile-with-firebase-security-rules)
- [Make a public profile and a private profile in angular 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739139/make-a-public-profile-and-a-private-profile-in-angular-4)
- [Firebase: Allow Read of property names, but not content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917435/firebase-allow-read-of-property-names-but-not-content)
- [How to store public/private data under a node, and still query the entire node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257960/how-to-store-public-private-data-under-a-node-and-still-query-the-entire-node)

Comment: Still not good, Frank. In this fashion, user-0002 for example can overwrite things for user-0005 for example. And of course: user-0002 can read any mailbox. It's important to isolate paths.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more and testing I conclude that this should work...

```
{
 "rules":{
  "users":{
     "$uid":{
        ".write":"$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read":"$uid === auth.uid",
        "mailbox":{
           "$uid":{
              ".write":" $uid === auth.uid"
           }
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

This means:

If I'm user-0001, I can read/write in anything at /users/user-0001, however I just can write in elsewhere if the path is /users/*/mailbox/user-0001